# How to remove empty space above the header and on each side?

Tags: html, css

Here is my HTML code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div>KK</div>
    </header>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is the css code:

```
html{
    margin: 0;
    font-size: 20px;
}
div{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
header{
    background-color: cornsilk;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;

}
```

I used zero padding and zero margin everywhere as I heard that header by default has indentations. But nothing seems to work(
thank you for your answers in advance!!

[image]

Comment: Just set padding and margin to 0 on the html and body elements.

Answer (score 2):

Problem was solved by adding to the css code

```
body{margin:0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `<body>` has a default margin of 8 pixels.
just add to the CSS code:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Even better would be:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```